# Structured type variable in shared or private openmp code

Tags: c++, c, openmp

I want to pass a variable as a shared variable in openmp parallel code but I am not exactly sure what should I do to pass a structured variable into shared variable. Here is my code: 
I am not sure if this is the right way to do this or not:

```
struct lvl{
int *L;
int *list;
};

struct lvl* lvls(int s,int k){
    struct lvl* lvls =malloc(sizeof (struct lvl));
    lvls->L = (int*)calloc(s+1, sizeof(int));
    lvls->list=(int*)calloc(k+1,sizeof(int));
    return lvls;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int n=100;
int k=200;
struct lvls *lvl = lvls(n,K);
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(threadnum) private(k,bi,b,kstart,kend,v,bmax,max,bwt) firstprivate(BinAff,Blist) shared(capacity,lvl)
 {
       #pragma omp for schedule (static,100)
        for (u=0;u<G->n;u++){
           //some code in here 
        }
  }
}
```

No I wanted to know if shared (lvl) is the right way to make both arrays of the struct (L and list )shared arrays? If not what should I do? I tried doing `shared (lvl->L,lvl->list)`  but I get some compilation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no arrays in your `struct`. There are only pointers. `lvl` is also just a pointer. The data sharing clauses (e.g. `shared`) only applies to the variable itself (the address `lvl` points to).

By the way, if you don't specify a data shared attribute, then variables defined outside the scope of parallel regions are implicitly `shared`. Variables defined inside are implicitly `private`. It is advisable to always define variables as locally as possible, it makes it easier to write correct code.

For example private variables, such as `k` are not initialized within the parallel region.